# What Positions on an Underlier CANNOT be Hedged with Vanillas?

Tags: exotics, replication

Say I have infinite precision of strikes $K$ (continuous world $dk$) and expirations $T$ (continuous $dT$) all with liquidity (so no practical limitations). What positions in an underlying can't be replicated? I'm under the impression I can replicate any European payoff, so if I had infinite expirations I could replicate really any position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any non path dependent European type payoff $f(S_T)$ can be replicated in a model independent way with vanilla calls and puts provided $f$ is twice differentiable (in the distribution sense). This is a consequence of the Carr-Madan formula.

Comment: I'm familiar with the replication formula... so is the distinction very clearly "path dependent payoffs cannot be replicated" with vanillas? Are there replication methods (separate from Carr-Madan) for path-dependent payoffs?

Comment: To clarify, any **non path dependent** European payoff $f(S_T)$ can be replicated with vanilla options in a **model independent way**, that is (as follows from the Carr-Madan formula) the replication weights depend only on the payoff function $f$, not on the model for the stochastic dynamics of $S_t$. For path dependent options in some cases it is possible to build static hedges but the weights depend on the model for $S_t$. See for instance static replication of barrier options and the paper by Andersen and al http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.407.6931&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

Gap risk contracts.

These are daily-restriking putspreads that pay & cancel only if the underlying drops more than (say) 20% as measured vs yesterday's closing level.

Contracts can range from as short as 6 months to 10 years.

Cannot replicate that using Europeans.